# Updating mysql table from datalist field

Tags: php, mysqli, datalist

I am trying to build a page on our work website.  The page allows you to create an activity which is then stored in a table in the mysql database.  One of the fields when you create the activity is 'assign to operative'.  This uses a drop down menu using the datalist options.  The datalist is populated automatically from the database table.  Although the code may not be the cleanest, it works well.

```
            <input list="assigned_to" name="assigned_to" placeholder="Please select..." required>
        <datalist id="assigned_to">
          <?php
          $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE idUsers = ?");
          $stmt->bind_param("s", $userId);
          $stmt->execute();
          $result = $stmt->get_result();
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $uidUsersFromAdmin = $row["uidUsersFromAdmin"];
            }
           $stmt->close();
           $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsersFromAdmin = ?");
           $stmt->bind_param("s", $uidUsersFromAdmin);
           $stmt->execute();
           $result = $stmt->get_result();
             while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
               $emailUsers           =   $row['emailUsers'];
               echo "<option value=\"$emailUsers\"></br>";
           }
            $stmt->close();
           ?>
        </datalist>
```

The problem comes in when I try to update the table.  If a user wishes to change something in the activity, the update_activity page brings in the same datalist and populates it perfectly, however, if someone hasn't change the 'assigned to' person, the field in the database table is replaced with blank space.

Please see the code below from the update page

```
            <input list="assigned_to" name="assigned_to" placeholder="<?php echo $assigned_to ;?>">
        <datalist id="assigned_to">
          <!-- This code brings in the 'operatives' from the users database -->
                        <?php
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsersFromAdmin = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $uidUsersFromAdmin);
                $stmt->execute();
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $uidUsersFromAdmin  =   $row['uidUsers'];
                    echo "<option value=\"$uidUsersFromAdmin\">";
                  }
                 $stmt->close();
               ?>            
        </datalist>
```

I have tried changing

```
<input list="assigned_to" name="assigned_to" placeholder="<?php echo $assigned_to ;?>">
```

to

```
<input list="assigned_to" name="assigned_to" Value="<?php echo $assigned_to ;?>">
```

but this just creates the one option, and I've tried using

```
 echo "<option selected value=\"$assigned_to\">";
```

but this didn't work either.  Help is much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish or what the issue is.

Comment: Hi, it's hard to explain. So the page allows the user to set an activity at work and allocate the task to someone.  They allocate the task by choosing a name from a drop down menu.  When creating the task the first time, this works. However, if they then edit the task, the same drop down menu is brought in, but this time it returns a blank result.  If they are editing the person they are allocating the task to, the table is updated with the new operative, but if they haven't changed that field, the field in the table becomes blank.

Comment: Please mark as closed - I solved the problem by using if(empty($assigned_to)) on the form action page!

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept it to close it.